# Ponteiros por parâmetro em C++

Tags: c++, referência

Estou tendo um problema com o ponteiro em `customers`. Chamo a função `newCustomer()`, que insere nós na lista pendurada em `customers`. O problema é que toda vez que o programa sai da função `newCustomer()`, `customers` volta a valer `nullptr`.

Segue abaixo a chamada de função, na `main()`:

```
case 1:
  newCustomer(customers);
break;
```

A função `newCustomer()` é esta:

```
void newCustomer(Cliente *customers){
 int num;
 string nome;
 Cliente *qwe, *next;
 cout << "Numero de clientes: ";
 cin >> num;
 qwe = customers;
 if(customers == nullptr){
   cout << "oi" << endl;
   customers = new Cliente();
   cout << "Nome do cliente: ";
   setbuf(stdin, 0);
   getline(cin, nome);
   customers->setName(nome);
   customers->setid(num);
   qwe = customers;
   num--;
 }
 while(qwe->getProx() != nullptr){
 qwe = qwe->getProx();

 }
 while( num != 0){
   next = new Cliente();
   qwe->setProx(next);
   qwe = qwe->getProx();
   cout << "Nome do cliente: ";
   setbuf(stdin, 0);
   getline(cin, nome);
   qwe->setName(nome);
   qwe->setid(num);
   num--;
 }
}
```

Gostaria também de pedir algumas dicas de como posso melhorar meu código. Estou começando em C++ agora, aceito todas as críticas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é porque você está iniciando customers dentro da função.

Pense dessa forma: o `customers` que você tem fora da função é um ponteiro que aponta para o endereço `10000`. O `customers` que você tem dentro da função é uma cópia do outro ponteiro, ele está alocado em uma posição diferente, mas também aponta para o endereço `10000`, ou seja tem o mesmo valor.

Se em algum ponto da função você alterar o valor que existe na posição `10000`, ambos os `customers` estarão apontando para esse endereço, e portanto o valor desse endereço irá refletir em ambos os ponteiros.

No entanto você não está alterando o valor no endereço `10000`, você está alterando o endereço para qual o ponteiro `customers` dentro da função está apontando. Agora o `customers` fora da função continua apontando para `10000`, mas o `customers` dentro da função aponta para `20000`, e portanto os valores não se refletem mais.

Se você quiser que o valor do `customers` dentro da função sempre reflita no `customers` fora da função, você precisa passar um ponteiro de um ponteiro, `Cliente **customers`. Ou ao menos é o que você precisaria fazer em C. Em C++ existe uma forma mais prática, você pode passar a referência de uma variável, dessa forma a variável dentro da função é tratada como sendo exatamente a mesma que a fora da função. Tudo que você precisa fazer é adicionar um `&` no argumento.

```
void newCustomer(Cliente *&customers) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Opa gostei dessa técnica. Bem simples e enxuta. Você saberia me dizer se usar isso causa lentidão, gasto extra de memória ou quaisquer outras consequências ruins?

Answer (score 1):

Na linha

```
customers = new Cliente();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/Constructor.cpp).

você está mudando o conteúdo de uma variável local, quando termina execução da função esta variável deixa de existir e seu valor desaparece. Por alguma razão você parece achar que esse valor sobrevive mesmo depois do fim da função, mas isto não acontece.

Seria possível usar `Cliente **customers` como parâmetro aí você altera o objeto da variável e não a variável em si, ou seja, você usa uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) para resolver o problema. Aí todo acesso ao objeto final será dado por um objeto intermediário que é um ponteiro para o objeto final. Esse ponteiro por ser um objeto passado pode ser alterado e será refletido lá fora. Claro, tem que passar o argumento de forma apropriada e o acesso ao objeto final tem que ser sempre través desse ponteiro, aí dá certo. Ou então pode retornar o objeto criado ali em vez de retornar `void`, oque pode ser mais simples.

Já que pediu dicas aí vão elas:

Na verdade isso tudo é programar em C usando o C++, em C++ real nada disso é considerado certo, ele tem mecanismos bem melhores que inclusive gerencia a memória automaticamente (este caso tem cara que vai vazar memória, pelo menos incentiva).

Uma função que cuida da inserção e a interface com o usuário não é adequado. As funções deveriam ter uma uma responsabilidade, aí tem duas. Isso pode criar problemas de manutenção. Em exercício não causa, mas se quer aprender cero é melhor se acostumar com isso.

O código parece fazer algumas coisas desnecessárias.

Poderia caprichar na formatação do código, pode parecer bobagem mais ajuda bem e costuma usar em minha palestra:

[image: Enquanto você não souber o que cada caractere do seu código faz, até mesmo o espaço em branco, você ainda não sabe programar]

Nem falei que me dá medo criar um único cliente em uma variável com nome no plural. Nomes adequados ajudam muito dar entendimento no código.

Comment: Saquei. Realmente, como você disse, eu aprendi a programar em C e não consigo disfarçar kkkkkk. Em C sempre passei ponteiros por referência daquele jeito, pensei que aqui também fosse dar certo. Fiquei curioso em saber sobre o C++ real. O que estou perdendo? Eu programo desse jeito mas quero aprender técnicas novas. Assisto a algumas video aulas no youtube, mesmo achando elas fracas, pois sãoo que tenho. Recomenda algum material onde posso programar com um estrutura mais formal, mais profissional?

Comment: Em C também não dá certo assim. Está perdendo muita coisa, C+= é uma linguagem totalmente diferente que por acaso compila códigos C. Praticamente todas videoaulas de C++ são ruins e ensinam tudo errado. Na verdade isso vale pra programação em geral, tem bem pouca coisa com qualidade. Sugiro procurar bons livros, bons cursos, mas de forma geral não indico nada, tem alguma indicação na descrição da *tag*. Eu só não começaria fazer coisas sem entender porque aquilo funciona ou não. Continuará seguindo receitas de bolo passadas por terceiros sem aprender.